# Centering & aligning elements inside a fieldset

Tags: css, fieldset

I currently have a fieldset which must take 96% of my container. This fieldset must have his elements centered but also aligned, so for example all the labels must end at the same spot and all the inputs must begin at the same spot.

This was fairly easy without the whole center problem with this code ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FhHQB/)):

```
.formulaire
{
    margin: 1em auto;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-color: #B0B0B0;
    padding: 1em;

}

.formulaire label
{
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    text-align: right;
}
```

I've tried to put my fieldset inside a div with text-align center, however it simply centers everything and doesn't align anything.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can wrap your form fields in a div, set the width to the longest label/field combination and then center that div with `margin:0 auto;`

[Here is the example](http://jsfiddle.net/FhHQB/)

Comment: Your example doesn't work here (Firefox Portable 18.0.1). However, I see what you meant... I was using this in the previous version of my website, however it leads to problem since it was not flexible enough (each fieldset had to have its own ID...)